# Вычислить произведение используя только побитовый сдвиг и сложение

Tags: c++

Пользователем указываются целые беззнаковые числа `a` и `b`. Вычислить произведение этих чисел, используя только операторы побитового сдвига и сложения.

Comment: в теории вы можете даже побитовый сдвиг не использовать. Просто в цикле добавлять...

Comment: Почитать методичку. Почитать булевую алгебру -  умножение двоичных чисел.

Comment: нет именно надо прм помощи побитового сдвига

Comment: связанный вопрос: [How can I multiply and divide using only bit shifting and adding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2776211/4279)

Comment: объяснение: [How to perform multiplication, using bitwise operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3722004/4279)

Comment: @pavel: это экспоненциальный O(2ⁿ) по количеству битов алгоритм (а алгоритм со сдвигом всего лишь квадратичный O(n²), а на практике вообще O(1) можно рассматривать для машинных слов).

Answer (score 3):

Что-то вроде

```
unsigned int mul(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    unsigned int prod = 0;
    while(a)
    {
        if (a != ((a >> 1) << 1)) prod +=b;
        a >>= 1;
        b <<= 1;
    }
    return prod;

}
```

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: `if (a != ((a >> 1) << 1))` это вы так `if (a & 1)` записываете?

Comment: @jfs - А что делать? оператор `&` в числе разрешенных не перечислен... Я даже вычитание и то побоялся использовать. Вот с `!=` не знаю, годится или нет :)

Comment: Это проясняет ситуацию. `sum` на `product` можно заменить. [Это работает (для маленьких типов по крайней мере).](https://ideone.com/riQ0mh)

Comment: @jfs А, да. переменную я назвал неудачно :(

Comment: @Harry можно заменить `a&1` на `a << 31 >> 31` вроде UB же нету. И на -O2 ассемблерный код одинаковый)